# How to set displayName in firebaseUser when registerwithemailpass

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i have to register a user with email password and then give him a name,is this possible without using firestore document for users to store names

```
dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase user profiles have a display name for the user, which you can update.

You'll want to call the [`updateProfile` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateProfile.html) on the `User` object, which takes a `displayName` argument.

Comment: UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: pass);
      _auth.currentUser.updateProfile(
        displayName: name,
      );  I did this it works now thanks